# pyparsing/nestedExpr - how to match some curly brackets used for nesting which are also part of literals?

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

I am trying to parse files that are formatted as below and some times same nestedExpr character is used within the literal that I need to extract as is.

Input:

```
      {
# some comment
        location 1 {
            command 1
        }
# this item is commented out
#        location 2 {
#            command 2
#        }
        location 3 {
            command 3 /tmp; PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH} ./abc.bat"
        }
        location 4 {
            command 4 -c "PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH} ls -l"
        }
    }
```

Actual output:

```
[['# some comment',
  'location 1 ',
  ['command 1'],
  '# this item is commented out',
  '#        location 2 ',
  ['#            command 2', '#        '],
  'location 3 ',
  ['command 3 /tmp; "PATH=/usr/bin:$', ['PATH'], './abc.bat"'],
  'location 4 ',
  ['command 4 -c "PATH=/usr/local/bin:$', ['PATH'], 'ls -l"']]]
```

Expected output:

```
[['# some comment',
  'location 1 ',
  ['command 1'],
  '# this item is commented out',
  '#        location 2 ',
  ['#            command 2', '#        '],
  'location 3 ',
  ['command 3 /tmp; "PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH} ./abc.bat"'],
  'location 4 ',
  ['command 4 -c "PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH} ls -l"']]]
```

As can be seen, I want my script to return "${PATH}" as is without parsing it into array.

Below you can see the code I tried and any help is greatly appreciated.

```
from pyparsing import nestedExpr, Combine, Literal, OneOrMore, CharsNotIn
from pprint import pprint
content =  Combine(OneOrMore(~Literal("{")
                                  + ~Literal("}") 
                                  + CharsNotIn('\n',exact=1)))
parser = nestedExpr(opener='{', closer='}', content=content)


inputStr = '''      {
# some comment
        location 1 {
            command 1
        }
# this item is commented out
#        location 2 {
#            command 2
#        }
        location 3 {
            command 3 /tmp; "PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH} ./abc.bat"
        }
        location 4 {
            command 4 -c "PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH} ls -l"
        }
    }'''


output = parser.parseString(inputStr, parseAll=True).asList()

pprint(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to expand your definition of `content` to explicitly detect these `"${...}"` elements before parsing the `CharsNotIn` term.

```
dollar = Literal("$")
substitution_expr = Combine(dollar + "{" + ... + "}")
content = Combine(OneOrMore(~Literal("{")
                            + ~Literal("}")
                            + (substitution_expr | CharsNotIn('\n', exact=1))
                            )
                  )

# content could be simplified to just this
content = Combine(OneOrMore(substitution_expr 
                            | CharsNotIn('{}\n', exact=1))
                  )
```

Making this change I get:

```
[['# some comment',
  'location 1 ',
  ['command 1'],
  '# this item is commented out',
  '#        location 2 ',
  ['#            command 2', '#        '],
  'location 3 ',
  ['command 3 /tmp; "PATH=/usr/bin:${PATH} ./abc.bat"'],
  'location 4 ',
  ['command 4 -c "PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH} ls -l"']]]
```

Comment: I was thinking in the same direction but doing it incorrectly. Thank you for the tip!